# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser denies to handle [invalid] HTML - first trial fails

Tags: php, html, perl, parsing, dom

g day dear community - hello all!

well I am trying to select either a class or an id using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser with absolutely no luck. Perhaps i have to study the manpages again and again.

Well - the DOM-technique somewhat goes over my head: 
But my example is very simple and seems to comply to the examples given in the manual (simplehtmldom.sourceforge AT net/manual.htm) but it just wont work, it's driving me up the wall. Other example scripts given with simple dom work fine.

See the example: http://www.aktive-buergerschaft.de/buergerstiftungsfinder

This is the easiest example i have found ... The question is - how to parse it?

Should i do it with Perl - The example HTML page is invalid HTML.
I do not know if the Simple HTML DOM Parser is able to handle badly malformed HTML
(probably not). And then i am lost.

Well: it is pretty hard to believe - but you can get the content with file_get_contents: But you afterwards have to  do the parser job!  And there i have some missing parts!

Finally: if i cannot get it to run i can try out some Perl parsers eg HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath

Comment: What doesn't work? Can you show some code?

Comment: hi Fosco hi Pekka, It is pretty hard to believe - but you can get the content with file_get_contents: But you afterwards have to  do the parser job!  And there is have some missing parts! Pekka and Fosco - can you help me here a bit!?

Answer (score 1):

1: check whether file_get_contents is working!!!!

2: If no use curl or fopen or telnet to read the data.

Simple Html Dom filters all the noise can process malformed tags also...

Problem might be with your data retrieving